# Broad topic in Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

Today I opened a new topic in the Documentation of "R Language". It is intended to summarize and describe useful functions and data structures in the field of GIS / geo data. However, there are many libraries, functions and data types which are interesting.

Yet, the "Parameters" section seems somehow to be limited to describe the parameters of single functions.

Thus I want to ask how to deal with very broad topics in Documentation?

Is SO Documentation only meant for syntax documentation, or also for documentation of complete workflows?

Comment: You could omit any sections not applicable to the topic.